Position of FaceGrids planes in Graphics3D
What is the position of FaceGrids used in Graphics3D?
The example below suggests it is at a depth around 2% of the plot box. Cuboid at 0.1 sits below the grid, cuboid at 0.3 sits above and the one at 0.2 blends with the grid partially. Interestingly, the cuboids at 0.1 or 0.2 are hovering above the grid plabe even though the grid is drawn over them.
Can I fix this? Can I place the FaceGrids at the very edge of the plot, i.e. at 0?
Version 14.1, MacOS
Graphics3D[
 {
  Cuboid[{3, 3, 0.1}, {7, 7, 0.1}],
  Cuboid[{3, 0.2, 3}, {7, 0.2, 7}],
  Cuboid[{0.3, 3, 3}, {0.3, 7, 7}],
  Sphere[{5, 5, 5}, 2]
  },
 Boxed -> False,
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}, {0, 10}},
 ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1},
 Lighting -> "Neutral",
 FaceGrids -> 
  Table[{face, {Range[0, 10, 1], 
     Range[0, 10, 1]}}, {face, -IdentityMatrix[3]}]
]



I can't reproduce exactly what you have written. It seems to be Mathematica version dependent. I suggest to use 3 different sizes for the cuboid so that they are easily recognizable, for example Cuboid[{4, 4, 0.1}, {6, 6, 0.1}],    Cuboid[{3, 0.2, 3}, {7, 0.2, 7}]   , Cuboid[{0.3, 2, 2}, {0.3, 8, 8}] . I guess the problem is linked with the option PlotRangePadding, but I have no time to investigate further today.

Indeed, it is version dependent. Prior to the upgrade from version 13, the grid lines were correctly not drawn over objects in front of the grid plane. PlotRangePadding -> 0 did not help.

This is reproducible in 14.1 on Windows. Rationalize changes nothing.

To avoid blending with the grid, use Style[Graphics3D[...], RenderingOptions -> {"3DRenderingMethod" -> "BSPTree"}] or any other of the similar methods mentioned in RenderingOptions.

@Domen Thank you, specifying RenderingOptions indeed solves the issue. I should have realized this is a problem of rendering. Would you like add this as an answer so I can accept it?

For the record, Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> False} did not help.

Oftentimes, weird overlapping artifacts in Graphics3D come from the Z-fighting. The first trick in the book is to change the "3DRenderingMethod" in RenderingOptions to one of the more accurate methods, such as "BSPTree":
Style[Graphics3D[...], RenderingOptions -> {"3DRenderingMethod" -> "BSPTree"}]



Why this does not work on cloud version?

@azerbajdzan, difficult to comment why, but note that rendering is done by the front-end, and especially in 3D graphics highly depends on the graphics hardware. I assume they decided it's not feasible for their Cloud servers to support this. Of course this is very clearly indicated in the documentation (top right).
